# Octave. A way to display numeric arrays and char arrays next to each other?

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave

I want to display matrices Yn (5x5), Un(5x1), Jn(5x1) in a format: Yn * Un = Jn, like this:

```
multiply_sign = [ nan; nan; '*'; nan; nan ];
equals_sign = [ nan; nan; '='; nan; nan ];
YnUnJn = [Yn, multiply_sign, Un, equals_sign, Jn]
```

I get an error, that the '*' and '=' vectors are char-arrays and Yn,Un,Jn are numeric-arrays. Is there perhaps a way to get round it?

In matlab it's possible to use uitable, but it's not implemented in Octave.

Input are Yn, Un, Jn matrix'es with dimention as specified above.

Output is YnUnJn matrix or whatever that looks like specified format: matrix Yn, then the "*" sign, then Un, then "=" sign, then Jn matrix.

Like this: [image: https://imgur.com/wUEKbyU]

Comment: Please also add the input and expected output. For me it's hard to guess which problem you are trying to solve

Comment: @Andy I'm trying to display 3 matrices one by one, with "*" and "=" signs separating them, like on the picture (that I've just added)

Comment: Which is your final purpose? For a kind of application, for a report? Perhaps creating and printing an image with results? Do you have a Matlab code for this? I think it is not straightforward under Octave nor under Matlab

Comment: Report purpose. Rahnema1's Answer is EXACTLY what was the goal of my long and painful endavour :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic implementation in Octave. Note that `disp` function in octave returns a string.

```
Yn = rand(5)-.5;
Un = rand(5,1)-.5;
Jn = rand(5,1)-.5;
b = blanks(size(Yn ,1));

dsp=@(x)char(strsplit(disp(x),'\n'));

multiply_sign = strjust(['*' b],'center').';
equals_sign   = strjust(['=' b],'center').';

disp([dsp(Yn) multiply_sign dsp(Un) equals_sign dsp(Jn)])


   0.1610588   0.1244556  -0.2046512  -0.1799725  -0.3302048    0.364565    0.167053
  -0.1774412   0.3618586   0.4974047   0.4349322  -0.4689669   -0.013163   -0.442009
   0.1016794  -0.0991844   0.4728800   0.2046589  -0.2876299*   0.091990=   0.405725
  -0.2048010  -0.4256928  -0.0517186   0.2915129  -0.3435698   -0.376725    0.342397
  -0.2740378  -0.0907411   0.0090493   0.4677547  -0.2294902   -0.136846    0.096984
```

.

In MATLAB you may need to use `evalc('disp(Yn)')`.